# Como utilizo pdfKit mediante un html?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, npm

Estoy utilizando la libreria pdfKit para generar un pdf, de la manera que lo realizo es mediante un string. Mi objetivo es realizarlo mediante una plantilla html. En la documentacion no encontre nada relacionado a esto.
Adjunto un extracto de mi codigo

```
//PD: El codigo funciona, solo quiero realizarlo mediante un html 
const stream = resp.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=invoice.pdf",
  });

  const doc = new pdfkit();
  doc.on("data", (chunk) => stream.write(chunk));
  doc.on("end", () => stream.end());
  doc.fontSize(20).text("Hola mundo");
  doc.end();
```

Hay alguna manera que en vez de pasarle un string pueda pasarle un html?.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No le pases el texto. Revisa [la documentación](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) y haz una transformación desde archivo (para que interprete el html; de otra forma, te va a pintar las etiquetas posiblemente). De paso, simplifica.

Sería algo como

```
import pdfkit

options = {
    'page-size':'A4',
    'encoding':'utf-8', 
    'margin-top':'0cm',
    'margin-bottom':'0cm',
    'margin-left':'0cm',
    'margin-right':'0cm'
}

pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'test.pdf', options=options)
```

Si definitivamente le quieres pasar el contenido del HTML como string, la documentación también indica cómo

```
body = """
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="pdfkit-page-size" content="Legal"/>
        <meta name="pdfkit-orientation" content="Landscape"/>
      </head>
      Hello World!
      </html>
    """

pdfkit.from_string(body, 'out.pdf') #with --page-size=Legal and --orientation=Landscape
```